# Use alembic.ini for configuring db connection charset

Tags: python, migration, database-migration, alembic

I am performing migrations using `alembic`.

Configuration is of course stored in the `alembic.ini` file.

I would like to have the encoding used when running the migrations as a configurable parameter.

Is there a field that can be used within `alembic.ini` to do so?

e.g.

```
[various_config]
migrations_encoding=latin1
```

so that the `sqlalchemy` url ends up being, e.g.

```
sqlalchemy.url = mysql+pymysql://user:password@db/db?charset=<the_value_above>
```

Comment: Did you fix this?
Can you post and answer?

Comment: Some interesting investigation here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50012917/flask-sqlalchemy-alembic-migration-sends-invalid-charset-to-pymysql but no answer